# Inventing, or avoiding, replacements for variable name 'class' in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Although "class" and "type" are reserved words in Ruby, categorizing content using workarounds with deliberate misspellings ("klass", "clasz") and needlessly wordy elaborations ("instrument_class" for a table named "instruments") give me the feeling that there's gotta be a better way. Is there a better synonym or approach in common use?

Comment: `type` is not a reserved word in any Ruby versions I know.

Comment: Not only is `klass` a common variable name, it's actually the [name of a method](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Reflection/AssociationReflection/klass) in Rails.

Comment: Why not just `Instrument`? Or, heavens forfend, `clInstrument` for an attribute holding the class?  (That said, I use `klass` sometimes, too, when I don't know what class I'm going to end up storing.)